# Core Data Entity Boolean property does not get saved on Table Cell delete

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have Core Data set up with help of RestKit 0.20 so Data is stored on the device, not in memory.
Saving new entities from responses works as well as setting and saving properties in success blocks.
However, when I try to set Bool property and save it in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {...
      Issue *issue = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    issue.toDelete = YES;
    [issue setHasBeenDeleted:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
    [self.managedObjectContext saveToPersistentStore:nil];
...
}
```

it does not get flushed to the disk. It does when I close the app.
I tried to use both main and child managedObjectContext, but result is the same.
What could have gone wrong?

Comment: I have just created dummy property called "dummy", and does get saved. Will create another Bool property and will see what happens.

Comment: have you set it to be Transient?

Comment: no, it was just checked as "optional"

Comment: probably it is something to do with meta data. I had once similar behaviour when I set Default Value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved a problem by introducing new Bool property called "deletedFromLibrary". Just using this variable everywhere "hasBeenDeleted" is used. "hasBeenDeleted" still does not get updated.